# Prevent the introduction of similar characters vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Is it possible to prevent entering characters that are already in the `textbox`?
like if I wrote in `textbox`
**abcd**
Then it is not allowed to write the same letters in it,
I searched and tried but could not find a way
All are about stopping letter gouging

Comment: yes it would be possible. Have you tried it yourself? You can check the current characters in the cell against what the user is currently typing. BTW is this a web application, or windows forms? Because the implementation of the solution would be quite different in each case

Comment: Yes I tried a little complicated way but it did not work, every letter entered is entered his ChrW number and prevented + its windows forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple, just use the following code:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
        e.Handled = TextBox1.Text.Contains(e.KeyChar)
End Sub
```

It'll help preventing typing the existing text(s) containing in a TextBox.

Hope it helps you!

[image: Text restrictor]

Comment: you just deleted a newspaper from the codes, thank you XD

Comment: LOL, glad to help. xD